# AjaxUpload plugin not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, file-upload, web-parts, ajax-upload

I have the following code to initialize the Ajax Upload settings in my js:

```
 new AjaxUpload($('.btnAdjuntar'), {
    action: '/_layouts/Company.PortalFFVV.SharePoint.WebParts/Handlers/UploadFile.ashx',
    onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
        if (!(ext && /^(jpg)|(png)|(gif)|(pdf)|(txt)|(avi)$/i.test(ext))) {
            showPopup('Solo se permite archivos de tipo images, audio , video , PDF y text. (Extensiones permitidas: jpg, png, gif, pdf, txt, avi).');
            return false;
        }
        this.setData({ 'accion': 'A', 'fileName': AdminArchivoExterno.filename, 'maxFileSize': DatosConsultaSession.TamanioAdjuntoMailing })
        showNofication("Espere un momento mientras se carga el archivo seleccionado...", "btnAdjuntar");
    },
    onComplete: function (file, response) {
        removeNofication(strStickyNotificationID, classButtonNotificaction);
        var resultado = new Array();
        resultado = response.split("%#%");

        if (resultado[0] == "True") {
            $('.txtDirectorioDatos').val(file);
            $('#divgvAdjuntos').html(resultado[2]);
        }
        else {
            $('.txtDirectorioDatos').val('');
            AdminArchivoExterno.filename = "";
            showPopup(resultado[1])
            return false;
        }
        CantidadAdjuntos = resultado[3];

    }
});
```

So the problem is that when I click the attach file button ('.btnAdjuntar') nothing happens. But it works fine in IE and Chrome.

The Attach button file is in a jquery modal.

I'm working with web parts (the js belongs to a web part) which are placed in a sharepoint page (im using vs 2012).

If you guys need more info, let me know. Thanks

Comment: Any console errors? Make sure the button element is loaded before constructing the AjaxUpload object.

Comment: Nope, there are no console errors and the constructor is in the Document.Ready function

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. Firefox, AjaxUpload in a Modal Dialog. button not responding. No errors in console. Super weird

Comment: how did u valid it ..means before upload no one can sumbit form

Comment: @user3209031 I don't quite understand your question, but this issue was solved as per the answer below. If you need clarification, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @MorganSoren , i mean to say ...how did u validate on submit ...means without upload of files , no one can submit form ...it should alert message " please select file "...

Comment: @user3209031 well, it was 4 years ago, so I'd be lying if I would say how, but I do remember that I used to have frameworks that validate the front end inputs when they were empty. That is my best guess, not completely sure since this was SharePoint. Sorry, cant be of more help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ajaxupload creates a div and then the input file control inside it. The z-index that it sets for the div is somehow too high for Firefox. 
Find the _createInput function in the plugin where it sets the z-index for the div. Change it to a lower value and retry.
The number that worked for me was 2147483